# Can you create a pair of entangled particles with asymmetric probabilities of quantum states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

Is it possible to create two entangled particles emitted such that the "left" particle has a different liklihood of being measured in a certain state than the "right" particle?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What experimental arrangement do you wish to understand?

Comment: In an entangled pair of particles, one particle isn't always in state A and the other in state B. They're always in opposite states (or in the same state, depending on the type of entanglement), but one particle is not going to be deterministically in one state.

Comment: I've added a bit to the question. But I'm trying to ask about whether its possible to create asymmetric entangled particles.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Why can't moderators be human beings and actually discuss their problems with the question? This is a perfectly reasonable physics question that hasn't been asked yet here.

Comment: Your question was closed because it is incomprehensible.  First you say your particles are entangled, then you say they have individual states.  These things cannot both be true, and we have no way of knowing which one you really mean.  If you posted a question to biology.stackexchange with a question about a cat that was also a reptile, I venture to guess that would be closed as well.   In any event, my answer below surely covers whatever it was that you actually meant to ask.

Comment: I have clarified what I meant. I've now removed the part you find confusing. But it sounds a bit hostile to say you have "no way of knowing" what I mean. Anyone can communicate with me to clarify, and I was actively working to clarify. That's the way of knowing. And your answer does not answer my question.

Comment: Actually my answer does answer the new version of the question.

Comment: @BT:  Don't take question closures personally.  They're designed to be temporary and reversible, to give the questioner an opportunity to clarify what they meant.  Without that, you could have several people interpret the question differently and post answers to questions that the questioner isn't actually interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "particle in state $A$" and
"particle in state $B$" are typos for "particle $A$" and "particle $B$".

> Is it possible to create an entangled pair of particles that consistently send the particle with state A left and the particle with state B right?

If the first particle is in state $L$ and the second in state $R$ ,then the state of the pair is $L\otimes R$, which is quite evidently not entangled.

> Alternatively, is it possible to do this such that the particle with state A is sent left more than 50% of the time on average?

Fix your favorite probability, other than $0$ or $1$,  for a left/right measurement on the first particle to yield ``left''.  Then almost any state with that probability will be entangled.  For example:

$$\left({1\over\sqrt3}\right) L\otimes L + \left({1\over\sqrt3}\right) L\otimes R
+\left({1\over2\sqrt3}\right)R\otimes L+ \left({1\over2}\right)R\otimes R $$

Comment: It wasn't a typo. I added a bit more to my question. I'm trying to ask if entangled particles can be created with asymmetric liklihoods.

Comment: @BT But in an entangled (pure) state, you cannot ascribe the individual particles an individual (pure) state - that's exactly the point of entanglement! Your new edit makes your question clearer (and in fact understandable), but it is 'contradicting' to the first part...

Comment: *It wasn't a typo.*  Then the first part of my answer answers your question.  Your particles are not entangled, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

> send the particle with state A left and the particle with state B right

By definition of "quantum"  the states are controlled by quantum *probability*  ( [$Ψ^*Ψ$)](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/qm.html) So the space state of individual events cannot be predicted. It is only conservation laws on quantum numbers that can show up the entanglement of the two particles  in an event..